# Open source FSK decoder library?

Tags: audio, telephony, audio-processing

I'm looking for a library or tool to decode FSK in wav files, e.g. caller id.

Currently using the tools bundled with vpb-driver for Voicetronix hardware that is available via debian/ubuntu. But this appears to have an error that I'm trying to debug -- a second tool to validate the audio file would be useful.

I'm **not** looking for any of the myriad tools that read caller id data from a modem or other hardware device -- I need pure software.

Comment: “[Minimodem](http://www.whence.com/minimodem/ "Minimodem") is a command-line program which decodes (or generates) audio modem tones at any specified baud rate, using various framing protocols. It acts a general-purpose software FSK modem, and includes support for various standard FSK protocols such as Bell103, Bell202, RTTY, TTY/TDD NOAA SAME, and Caller-ID.”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try SpanDSP http://www.soft-switch.org/

Lots of good stuff in there, including FSK.